# Run RStudio Server on Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: rstudio, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rstudio-server

I installed RStudio Server on the Linux Subsystem on my Windows 10 machine, but my browser won't connect to `http://localhost:8787`.  When I run `sudo rstudio-server verify-installation`, I get the error `Unable to connect to Upstart`.

I know WSL doesn't support Upstart or systemd; how can I run RStudio Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can start RStudio Server without Upstart or systemd by running `exec /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver` at the Bash prompt.

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks for putting this up here. I am trying to do the same thing but keep getting a permissions error (`[rserver] ERROR system error 13 (Permission denied)`). Could you tell me what verison of rstudio-server you're running? I'm using `1.1.463`.